# How does the mainloop know how to respond to a given packet?

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

In the MathLink / WTSP mainloop different packets get passed to a kernel in "MathLink mode" and the kernel has a specific response for each. I can guess how the kernel picks a response, generally, but it'd be nice if there were some way to know the "canonical" response.

Does such a thing exist and is there any way to access it?

Comment: I have no idea about what happens inside math kernel. But the WSTP C API `WSGetType` retrieves a "type token" which tells the data type to be read from link.

Comment: @user1950580 the question is primarily what the return type should be

Comment: @user1950580 that is useful info though, thank you

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. Do you want a table listing the possible response packet types for each type of packet sent?

Comment: @Szabolcs I was hoping there'd be a function that'd implement this that I could piggy back on top of. If not a table is fine.